# Problems on deriving cumulative distribution function

Tags: integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, self-learning

I need some insights on solving the probability and statistics problems. Specifically, I was studying a review notes and among my searches I encountered this [link](http://www.math.wm.edu/~leemis/chart/UDR/PDFs/StandarduniformStandardtriangular.pdf).

I understood the proof by plotting the equation for $x_2-x_1 \leq y$ using different values of y and it took me a long time. I passed calculus and statistics long time ago and I am not skilled in solving these problems. My question is plotting the equation is the only way to writing the integration boundaries? Is there any methods that can be done faster with less error rather than plotting?

I appreciate any insights you can provide.

Thanks.

Comment: For sums of independent continuous random variables, it turns out that the probability density of the sum is always the convolution of the densities. So you could have realized this as $f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X_1}(x) f_{X_2}(y-x) dx$ where $f_{X_1}(x)=1$ if $x \in [0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise and $f_{X_2}(x)=1$ if $x \in [-1,0]$ and $0$ otherwise

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is this another approach to solve the problem? I don't quite understand the way you wrote it. What is variable x?

Comment: $x$ is just the variable of integration.

Comment: :( What should I study to understand this? Convolution of the densities?

Comment: I read about the convolution of the densities and I see how you wrote it. I actually want to use the way this problem to other problems that does not mentioned the independence of variables. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without independence there are very few shortcuts except in highly special cases.